# How to render to a specific mip-level in OpenGLES?

Tags: android, opengl-es

Anyone know how to render to specific mip-level texture?

Currently I am binding the mip-level texture by:

```
        glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0,
            GL_TEXTURE_2D, textID, mip-level);
```

Then later in my code, I will do something like this:

```
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, FBO_ID);
    drawArrays(...);
```

But I the shader is not executed!!!

Answer (score 1):

If textID is anything other than 0, this should be generating a `GL_INVALID_VALUE` error.

- `GL_INVALID_VALUE` is generated if level is not 0 and texture is not 0.

I suggest you take a look at [`glFramebufferTexture2D` for OpenGL ES](http://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glFramebufferTexture2D.xml). It is valid to do what you want in normal OpenGL but not in OpenGL ES :-\

Comment: I need to render to a specific mipmap level in OpenGL ES2.0 (Android), Is there anyway I can do this?